# Reload masonry Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using masonry in the list of cards, when i am adding new card i need to reload masonry. I don't know how to call function for reloading masonry

```
mounted(){
  let wrapper = this.$refs.wrapper;
  let msnry = new Masonry(wrapper, {
    itemSelector: '.note',
    gutter: 10,
    percentPosition: true
  });
}

watch: {
  array: function(val) { // watch it
    if(val){
      msnry.reloadItems(); // function for reloading items
      msnry.layout(); // function for rerendering layout
    }
  }
}
```

Maybe msnry should be defined globally? But in the React tutorial, it calls in the same way. How could i deal with it

Comment: Your msnry object is locally defined. You need to define it in your data option so you can later use it in other methods.

Comment: @Allkin Your comment is true, but it not solves the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you think About using a Vue Component for it?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-masonry

This one should automaticly render new Cards etc.

Answer (score 0):

#### To solve your problem

I'm not sure what your `<template>` looks like, but you probably want to set your watcher to watch `array` deeply:

```
watch: {
  array: {
    deep: true,
    handler: function(val) { // watch it
      if(val){
        msnry.reloadItems(); // function for reloading items
        msnry.layout(); // function for rerendering layout
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There's more info [in the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch).

#### Using a masonry component

There is also this masonry vue component that might make things easier for you:
https://github.com/shershen08/vue-masonry

It's based on the same library, but it wraps it up nicely and makes it easy to use within other Vue components.